# How do I specify Java dependecies in Guidewire's v10 build.gradle file?

Tags: gradle, guidewire

We are using GW ClaimCenter 10.2. Within our application we use several external Java dependencies, e.g. `jackson-databind`.
Up until now we used to put those JARs into the folder `ClaimCenter/modules/configuration/plugins/shared/basic/lib`.

Since we migrated from v8 to v10 a couple of months ago, we were wondering if we could leverage the "new" Gradle build system to import those dependencies.
We tried to specify the dependencies like this in `ClaimCenter/modules/configuration/build.gradle`:
[image: build.gradle]

Unfortunately, GW Studio did not recognize the dependencies and the application failed to start.

Is there a way to define and use external dependencies in Gradle for GW ClaimCenter?

Comment: What error did you get when the application failed to start? Do you mean it recognizes the changed gradle file when you do a re-build or did you run another gradle task to make it re-compile the `build.gradle` file?

Comment: I got compilation errors because the referenced packages were not found. There were no errors in the `build.gradle` file. I did not run any Gradle tasks specifically, instead I tried to built the project in GW Studio.

Comment: I don't think the changes to configuration level `build.gradle` are being detected by Guidewire during a normal build from studio. They have also disabled the sync gradle option in Studio. Are you certain that the changes are being scanned and applied? On a typical gradle project `./gradlew build` would trigger it but that doesn't happen for GW Studio.

Comment: Exactly, I agree with you. I do not think GW Studio does anything with `build.gradle`. Also there is no Gradle wrapper or anything similar. So, I guess it does not work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The challenge is that any modification to the project or configuration level `build.gradle` files is not detected while building the project in Guidewire Studio which has intentionally been modified to get rid of build tools support. I figured out a way to generate the gradle wrapper by running `gwb wrapper`. Then using the wrapper we can run `gradlew.bat build` and force a re-compile of project-level and configuration-level gradle files. However, Studio still doesn't detect the jar, and while some hacks can allow you to add a jar to the WAR / EARs classpath, it may not be recommended to do so. Out of the box, it appears that all dependencies are loaded from the `repository` jar or Guidewire expects the jars to be present in one of the local directories of the source code. One of the below files can be modified to add `mavenCentral()` as a valid repository along with the `compile` or `implementation` dependency.

1. Platform level `build.gradle` that is present in the project root.
2. Configuration level `build.gradle`
3. `gw-build.gradle` present in `modules/script`

Also make sure to register the central maven repository using

```
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url rootProject.file('repository') }
  }
```

The recommended and correct way to add external libs is to stick to the `plugins/shared/lib` folder. Please note that `plugins/shared/basic` has been deprecated post v8 and should be avoided. Any modifications or tweaks made to the above gradle files would be putting your project at constant risk of a minor version upgrade overwriting one of the files. So while what you are looking to achieve is doable, it is not the recommended or correct way of adding dependencies. It appears that Guidewire uses Gradle mostly for building the platform level and studio code and doesn't expect customers to modify it. Placing a jar in a local directory and then referencing it in the `build.gradle` file defeats the purpose of having a gradle-based dependency management and that's why the former approach is safer.

Comment: Thank you for you thorough investigation and explanation. :)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it myself, but the build.gradle file includes the following commented example.

```
// Example 4: add additional JAR to Java classpath and WEB-INF/lib in WARs
/*
dependencies {
  compile files(rootProject.file('my-libs/library.jar'))
}
*/
```

Note that newer versions of InsuranceSuite upgrade Gradle to v8 which can break current customizations due to changes in the way dependencies are handled.  I have no idea if this suggestion will be impacted by that change.

Comment: Will this work for loading dependencies from a remote repository? It appears that `rootProject.file()` attempts to load the jar from a local directory `my-libs` instead. Wouldn't that be equivalent to placing the jar in `plugins/shared/lib` folder?

Comment: I can't really answer that - I'm not any kind of gradle expert.  I'd guess it's possible given gradles capabilities.  I skimmed this doc and I'd guess the answer is in here somewhere.
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html#declaring-dependencies

Comment: Yeah, I tried that defining `compile group: 'com.microsoft.azure', name: 'msal4j', version: '1.14.2'`. Unfortunately, the build fails...